# Как написать регулярное выражение для поиска текста после тире?

Tags: php, строки

Всем привет мне надо написать регулярку для этого примера test - user и чтобы результатом было только user, кто то может с этим помочь?

Comment: /.*\-\s*(.*)/sgm   Проверяйте на сайте https://regex101.com/

Comment: [`-\s*\K.*`](https://regex101.com/r/juJOf9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Регулярки не нужны в конкретном случае

```
$str = 'test - user';
$result = trim(explode('-', $str)[1]);
```